# a neon light was held to a dipole antenna would it light up because the gas inside would be ionised?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

if a neon light was held to a dipole antenna would it light up because the gas inside would be ionised? in if not, why not? And is there a type of antenna that could concentrate all radio waves in the area?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if high frequency electromagnetic field is strong enough, it can cause a discharge in gas (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glow_discharge#Powering_modes).

Answer (score 0):

I heard a story some years ago where some private garden owners without power line, but located close to a commercial radio station lit their garden houses exactly that way, consuming a significant portion of the radio station's power.